# Cannot Update packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.04, updates, sudo

i am fairly new to Ubuntu. so i don't really have much knowledge about the command lines and Os.

I have been trying to use the command :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But its showing these errors.

[image: Errors]

[image]

I don't understand a single thing.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @karel I tried doing it. But it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm5XV.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like ubuntu's public keys were deleted by your system. I think you can open the program "software & updates" and goto "Ubuntu software", uncheck and check all of the checkboxes and try again. if it dosent work comment on this que and I'll be happy to help :)

Edit: it seems like it wants some packages to be re-installed. can you open a terminal and type these cmds:

`sudo apt upgrade | grep error`

I know they'll be a error. please post back the error :)

Edit: final fix: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-gpg-error-the-following-signatures-couldn-t-be-verified

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried what you said. It showed this : [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD2kk.png)

Comment: @Silver I have edited the answer :)

Comment: Its showing this : [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0vpG.png)

Comment: @Silver try updating now

Comment: It shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm5XV.png)

Comment: @Silver https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-gpg-error-the-following-signatures-couldn-t-be-verified

Comment: The problem was solved. Thanks a lot for giving me your time and help :)

Comment: @Silver pls accept my answer if it solved it!

Comment: I did it. Sorry for the delay. I am new to all this stuff. Thanks for the help